# multiple counts with different values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a table like this:

```
+------+--------+------+
|Color |Shape   |Type  |
+------+--------+------+
|red   |square  |puzzle|
|red   |circle  |puzzle|
|green |star    |puzzle|
|green |circle  |puzzle|
|blue  |square  |puzzle|
|blue  |star    |puzzle|
|blue  |triangle|puzzle|
+------+--------+------+
```

and I wanted to get results that looked like this:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
|redCount|blueCount|squareCount|
+--------+---------+-----------+
|2       |3        |2          |
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

how might I change the following query to actually work, or can it simply not be done in this manner?

```
SELECT COUNT(Color="blue") AS blueCount,
 COUNT(Color="red") AS redCount,
 COUNT(Shape="square") AS squareCount
 FROM toys
 WHERE Type = "puzzle";
```

Comment: Does it have to be columns? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try using `IF`

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(`Color` = 'blue', `Color`, null)) AS `blueCount`
     , COUNT(IF(`Color` = 'red', `Color`, null)) AS `redCount`
     , COUNT(IF(`Shape` = 'square', `Shape`, null)) AS `squareCount`
FROM `toys`
WHERE `Type` = 'puzzle';
```

or `CASE` :

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN `Color` = 'blue' THEN `Color` END) AS `blueCount`
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN `Color` = 'red' THEN `Color` END) AS `redCount`
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN `Shape` = 'square' THEN `Shape` END) AS `squareCount`
FROM `toys`
WHERE `Type` = 'puzzle';
```

Comment: you have to add ) in all your count